# Create Features Using Feet Temporarily

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, units

I do a lot of parcel editing and have it in a topology set to a UTM coordinate system. 99% of all survey plans I add into the parcel fabric are using metres as there unit. That 1% of the time I get a survey plan in feet always takes me 10x longer to input. This is basically just because I cannot on the fly set the editing units from metres to feet.

I really hope that there is an easy way to set the edit units from metres to feet, but I haven't been able to find anything so far. Right now I have to copy all the units from the plan into excel, convert them from feet to metres and then start imputing the plan. I figured it'd be easy, like there would be an on the fly conversion tool within ArcMap, but I haven't found one. I also though it'd be easy to simply change the map units, but they are greyed out:

[image: Data Frame]

I can't fathom that I am the only one having this issue and I know ESRI has to have some sort of way of optimizing this process. So please show me where the on the fly editor conversion is.

Comment: There is a way to set units within the Editing toolbar (so you can enter distances in, e.g., feet even though your projection is in meters)... which I haven't used for at least a year so it will take me a moment to remember which menu it's in!

Comment: @Erica Thats Awesome! I scoured that toolbar and couldn't find it in 10.2.2

Comment: I found it in 10.2.1 and I doubt they've moved it -- hope that works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remembered doing this for a project a while ago, but it took me a while to re-find the menu!

In the Editor toolbar, open up the Options dialog and go to the Units tab. Enter a **Distance Factor** that converts from units you have (e.g. feet) to your projection units (e.g. meters).

[image: screenshot of editing options / units window]

See [About distance units and editing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000036000000) for some common conversion factors.

Ground to Grid correction can also be found [on the COGO toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000mz000000.htm), if you're using that approach for editing/creating data.

Comment: Holy smokes. How did I not realize this is what this does. THANKS!!!!

Comment: The biggest trick is remembering to set it back to 1 when you're done :)